# Top bar pending-review count is wildly out

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues, top-bar

For a number of days now, the top bar pending-review count has been *wildy*, **wildly** out. Now, I know caching etc. is employed here, and the count is often off by a *few*, but for the last few days the counter has been out by ~50 *everytime I've looked at it*, and my OCD can't deal with it any more...

> [image]

I count 450, but the pill shows 497... in fact, I posted this question, refreshed `/review`, then pill goes up to 520, but there are actually 456 to review.

---

**EDIT:** Ok, so it's been a week now... and I'm still not convinced this is caching, and [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). The pill currently shows **675** posts for review, yet adding up all the queues (less Close votes) I get 385. Caching should **not** be almost 100% out. If this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), it's [status-poordesign](/questions/tagged/status-poordesign).

---

**Edit 2**; a few more days later, and the pill is showing **1137**, vs. the **290** that is actually available to review.

Comment: Are they related to the close vote review queue?

Comment: @TravisJ: I always thought it excluded the CV queue?

Comment: Matt - I was not sure so I kind of threw the question out there :)

Comment: It might be cached.

Comment: [Should I blame caching?](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: @Sklivvz: I get caching, but the pill is currently out by a factor of 100%.

Comment: Broke into quadruple digits this morning. I saw 1012. I wonder if this is a result of the new Improvement feature, and/or changes to triage.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the data is cached.  That number is the same for everyone who has sufficient privledges to see it.  It counts the number of reviews that are able to be completed (on SO, excluding the close review queue).  If you have done some suggested edit reviews that are still waiting for a second or third, those don't show up as "able to be done" in your /review page, but they are counted on the orange tab.

The reason for this is [caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/). Rendering the /review page is expensive enough... counting how many there are for *just you* can't be cached and on each page load... that would eat some cpu time.  Multiply that by the number of users who see it and that's a lot.

So, the top indicator is cached.  it counts the total number that can be done and caches it for a period of time.  It may be off because of caching. It may be off because you partly completed some reviews that are still open (triage can need up to 7 reviews in cases of dissagreement).

See also from MSE: [Notify users of possible reviews on toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726/213963)

> It is also cached, so may or may not be very accurate depending on the amount of ongoing activity in /review at any given time.

and

> Correct, @gnat: this is everything in review, even stuff that you, personally, can't review. Super-expensive to personalize this - so the alternative is simply not having an indicator. Think of it as... A reminder to encourage your peers to review. –  Shog9♦ Apr 29 '14 at 22:29
>
> @FreshPhilOfSO Not bugged. The topbar count is every review in the system, not just the ones available to you (ie ones you haven't skipped or already otherwise acted on). –  Anna Lear♦ Apr 30 '14 at 2:06

Comment: Please see my latest update. I understand caching is employed here, but something *seriously* seems amiss at its inaccuracy here.

Comment: @Matt the number is the amount of open reviews. If you have few actionable reviews (because you've already acted on them), then the number can be quite a bit off.  On Programmers.SE the number on the top bar is 82, my available reviews is 15 because there are 67 reviews I've cast votes on that haven't been completed yet.  This is as designed.

Comment: I haven't actioned 300 reviews in the past month (which is the amount the pill is off by), let alone few days.