# Inaccurate review counter?

Tags: support, review-queues

My rep just turned 10k. All of the sudden, my review counter jumped from maybe 10 or 20 to 1600, but I didn't see any new review category, and the math is wrong (8k pending close reviews, 54 low quality, nothing else above 10).

Where do those 1600 pending reviews come from? Is there a link I didn't see?

Comment: I also see such a huge number (1578)... not sure where those come from...

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I'm referring to the review counter in front of the review link on top of the page.

Comment: Cross-site related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238515/158100

Comment: It's been on the fritz for the past week and a half or so.  There is no discernible correlation between the displayed value and the actual number of pending reviews in the various queues.  Something isn't getting reset, I'd guess.

Comment: Looking at this [sede query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/291862) it looks like we have much more suggested edits active than are shown on /review page. Close reviews were never part of the number in the topbar btw.

Comment: @rene You're right, and excluding the clos vote review makes the math far more accurate. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I thought you were talking about your own completed reviews, not the currently pending reviews. That would make sense.

Comment: Yes, while the number has been off for quite some time, I also noticed that it has been **WAY** off the last few weeks.

Comment: I reported this as a bug over a week ago... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287320/top-bar-pending-review-count-is-wildly-out. It got marked [meta-tag:status-by-design], attributed to caching, and closed as a year-old-duplicate. FML.

Comment: There's something causing a massive buildup of bogus review tasks in the suggested edit queue. The actual number of tasks are reasonable (and falling) - I'm investigating the counter issue.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The numbers on [`/review`](https://stackoverflow.com/review) are a lie (and [caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221414/158100)) and is discussed before [on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238515/158100)

The topbar counter jumped when you reached 10K probably because it unlocked the [moderator tools privilige](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) which also gave you access to the full review history of all users in all queues.

You can reconstruct the number you see if you take a look at this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/291862) (updated last saturday).

```
count               |name                |name 
-------------------------------------------------               
8221                |Close Votes         |Active              
   2                |First Post          |Active              
   5                |Helper              |Active              
 162                |Low Quality Posts   |Active              
1412                |Suggested Edit      |Active              
  19                |Triage              |Active
```

and notice that the close vote review count was never part of the number of available reviews in the topbar. If you leave those out of the above numbers we get close to the 1600 you see.

The suggested edit count is most off in the /review page and that has probably to do with the review-lock that is applied to suggested-edit reviews as explained [in this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270169/578411) from [Geoff Dalgas](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2/geoff-dalgas)

> It's a bit like ticketmaster, or any type of reservation system. When you visit a suggested edit review task it's now "checked out" to you for that time - the counter previously didn't reflect the amount of "checked out" tasks.

So to conclude: In the topbar you see all available reviews site wide (excluding close votes on SO) and on /review you see the number of tasks available for you personally. Depending on locks and caching those numbers vary.

Comment: Interesting point about the review-lock for edits causing the increase in the counter. While caching will affect the number somewhat, the lock is clearly the cause. I wonder, will this number continue to rise, or will it level out as the number of users editing levels out.