# Why the tilde symbol appears in front of the suggested edit review count?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

Why the tilde symbol appears in front of the suggested edit review count?

It means "approximately"? If so what is the need of this here?

Screenshot for the reference:

> [image: Approximate Count]

Comment: [It's cached](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233536/260312)

Comment: That number is a [lie](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288556/578411)

Comment: The usual meaning of `~` before a number is *approximately*, so I'm going to say it means **approximately 34 edits pending approval**.

Comment: to forestall the hundreds of meta questions asking why this number is different than the actual number of pending edits.